# $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\frac{p-1}2}3^k\binom{p}{k}\equiv 2^p-1\pmod{p^2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, binomial-coefficients

Let $p$ be prime and $p\ge5$. My friend askes me the following

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\frac{p-1}2}3^k\binom{p}{k}\equiv 2^p-1\pmod{p^2}$.

Here $\binom{p}{k}=\frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}$ for any $k=0,\ldots,p$. We define $0!=1$.

I think this is true, but I have no idea to attempt it.

Comment: Via a sequence of reductions using Wilson's theorem, the result is equivalent to $$\sum_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} (-1)^k \frac{3^k - 2}{k} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$

Comment: Interesting observation: Rearrange and we can get $$\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}3^k}{k} = 2\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$$. Here the left side is kind of like $ln(4)$ and the right side is kind of like $2ln(2)$

Comment: This is problem N2 from USA ELMO Shortlist 2011. See [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h487132).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole credit of this answer goes to [math154 on AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h487132).

---

Given that $1\leq k\leq\frac{p-1}{2}$ we have
$$ \binom{p}{k}=\frac{p}{k}\binom{p-1}{k-1}\stackrel{\text{Lucas}}{\equiv}\frac{p}{k}(-1)^{k-1}\equiv 2(-1)^k\frac{p}{2k}(-1)^{2k-1}\equiv 2(-1)^k\binom{p}{2k}\pmod{p^2} $$
so the problem boils down to evaluating
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}2\binom{p}{2k}(-3)^k\stackrel{\text{DFT}}{=}(1+\sqrt{-3})^p+(1-\sqrt{-3})^p \equiv 2^p\pmod{p^2} $$
where the last equality follows from the fact that if $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity, $1+\omega^m+\omega^{2m}=0$ for any $m\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus 3\mathbb{Z}$.